# Android: ListPreference gets app out of full screen mode

Tags: android

I have a single activity app that uses only one Activity and then several fragments with Android Jetpack's navigation system. I don't think this is relevant, but just in case.

To get the activity in full screen mode I use this inside its OnCreate method:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY );
```

That works fine most of the time, but when I enter in my settings fragment and touch on a ListPreference like this:

```
    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="Front"
        app:entries="@array/camera_device_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/camera_device_entry_values"
        app:key="@string/settings_camera_device_key"
        app:title="@string/settings_camera_device_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

The application gets out of the full screen mode and the app title even conceals part of the top setting. How could I avoid this?

I'm testing in a real device Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 9.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This has been more complicated than expected, but it seems Android has this tendency to make solutions to simple requirements quite complex very often just because whatever...

First, change the app theme. We need to use a descendant of AppCompat, so I created this theme in values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then this needs to be put in the AndroidManifest.xml file, on the <application ... section since this is a single activity app so it'd be pointless to declare a per activity theme:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Even with that when I open the settings the full screen mode will break because it will show the navigation buttons as soon as I tap on the ListPreference setting and then those buttons will stay there even when going back to the previous fragment.

Notwithstanding, I realized these are fine in the SettingsFragment actually, thus I want to force them to show even before tapping the ListPreference setting, and then I want them to hide when comming back from such fragment.

This has to be done from the MainActivity but called from some Fragments, so next step was to create an interface:

```
public interface InmersiveActivity {
    void setInmersiveMode(boolean enabled);
}
```

Then the MainActivity has to implement it as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InmersiveActivity

...

public void setInmersiveMode(boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    } else {
        // If not enabled, we just leave the navigation buttons there
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Now, the first fragment is called StartFragment, and the SettingsFragment is always open from that one, so I added this to such StartFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);

    InmersiveActivity activity = (InmersiveActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setInmersiveMode(true);
...
```

That's called always when the fragment is created for first time but also when it comes back from other fragment deeper in the navigation graph.

Then in the OnClick handler for the button that opens the SettingsFragment from the StartFragment:

```
activity.setInmersiveMode(false);
findNavController(StartFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_settingsFragment);
```

That does the trick.

I hope this helps someone else.